# Method to disable input text using javascript until a function is completed

Tags: javascript, html

I have a input box and I want to temporarily disable input until a function completes in javascript and then re-enable it.
I know the element.disabled = true and element.disabled = false (doing that after the function) won't bring it back to the enabled state since I use onkeydown to enable the function, the code is somewhat like this->

HTML:

```
<input type=text id=text1 onkeydown=myfunction(event)/>
```

Javascript:

```
function myfunction(event) {
  var EnterKeyPressed = verifyKeyPressed(event, 13);
  if (EnterKeyPressed == true) {
    //here is where i want to disable the text box
    fade(someotherOtherElement);
    //i want to re enable it here
  }
}
```

Basically its just a text box with onkeydown, when you normally type it keeps going on, but when you press enter (keyCode = 13) it verifies that with javascript event and if true , submits the value of the textbox after the fade. I want the entry to text to be disabled while fading as it results to a partial fade upon posting something else quickly after the first post. the element.disabled = true and after fade(), elem.disaled = false doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

Use it's Id:

```
document.getElementById('text1').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('text1').disabled = false;
```

Or, give your input field a name, and make sure it's in a form (also with a name):

```
document.myForm.myField.disabled=true;
document.myForm.myField.disabled=false;
```

Comment: i tried that , doesnt work, i think its because once you disable it the onkeydown function in which the fade is , doesnt work because its disabled so you cant re enable it by itself and would need another enabled element for it to be enabled. thanks for the help

Comment: Eh... ok... it's the same code as you said "thanks a lot for" just without the jquery.

Comment: +1 for your answer and comment bro. Too bad that your answer was not marked as the selected answer. Give a noob a JS library and he will shoot his chubby head off.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using jQuery, there is a nice and easy option using the .attr and .removeattr APIs, I use it to disable a submit button like this.

```
    $('#itemAdd').submit(function(){
        $('input[type=text]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
```

To enable the element again you can use

```
    $('#itemAdd').submit(function(){
        $('input[type=text]', this).removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
```

API code is available here for [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and here for [.removiceattr](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/8te6c/

html:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("#text1").keydown(function(e) {
    var EnterKeyPressed = verifyKeyPressed(e, 13);
    if (EnterKeyPressed === true) {
        //here is where i want to disable the text box
        var that = this;
        that.disabled = true;

        $('#fadeMe').fadeOut(500, function() { // fadeOut's callback function
            //i want to re enable it here
            that.disabled = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("text1").setAttribute("disabled", false);
```

It worked for me successfully

Answer (score 0):

you said that

```
elem.disaled = false
```

does not work

> Try this:

```
 document.getElementById("elem")..removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Its worked for me